# Unable to read remote registry

Tags: .net, security, exception, remote-registry

Trying to read registry keys remotly (from a host on local intranet)...

- All the permissions are set in **local + remote machines**..
- Also, the *remote registry service* is running on both machines..
- Still i get **unauthorized access exception** (and sometimes handle is invalid error) when trying from .net code (both frameworks tried: v4.0/v3.5-sp1).

Any ideas?? Help is appreciated..

Comment: Is it a domain user trying to access or you have a workgroup?

Comment: both machines are on same domain

Comment: I am trying to access remote machine by its name (not ip or domain name).. is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with my antivirus program. After I disabled it, everything works fine.

Comment: Do be sure to accept this answer to mark the question as resolved as soon as the system will let you do so. Look for the hollow checkmark on the left side.